# How to linearize difference of absolutes?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, modeling

How to linearize difference of absolutes?

$$|a|\ge k|b|$$

where $a,b$ are variables and $k$ is a constant.

Comment: The feasible set isn’t convex so this can’t be done in linear programming.  Do you want an answer involving integer variables?

Comment: Sure...I will try if I can convert my problem to integer variables.

Comment: You can find helpful things in here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=7518cd88-d670-460f-8f9a-aafffe8fc9a1

Comment: Please see the question and answer here: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3/working-with-absolute-values-in-constraint-in-a-lp-or-milp. If that doesn't answer your question sufficiently, then please revise your question to indicate what's still unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

Create some extra variables

$AB_1, AB_2, X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$, and you have $a,b,k$

\begin{align}a &= X_1-X_2\\AB_1 &= X_1+X_2\\b &= X_3-X_4\\AB_2 &= X_3+X_4\\AB_1 &\geq k \cdot AB_2\end{align}

Also, you have to minimize variable $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ and $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4 \geq 0$

Comment: Is it possible to create constraints without objective function? I have another objective functions in my problem

Comment: you can multiply it with an small value so that it doesn't have any impact on your objective function. Like this `your current objective function +  (x1+x2+x3+x4)*0.00000000001` some thing like this. You can also try it without adding objective function.

Comment: The small penalty approach is not entirely safe. If a solution with $|a|<k|b|$ produces a sizeable improvement in the objective function, the solver will "pad" $X_1$ and $X_2$ to make the solution look feasible and accept the small penalty.